# Using Perl to create another Perl file

Tags: perl

I have an input file that looks like

```
*firsttitle
nameA
nameB
nameC
*secondtitle
xnameA
xnameB
xnameC
```

I want to create a Perl script that takes this file and basically will *create another perl script* that looks like

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

        use strict;
        use warnings;

        my %tags = (
            "firsttitle" => [ qw (nameA nameB nameC) ],
            "secondtitle" => [ qw (xnameA xnameB xnameC) ]);

 my $rx = join '|', keys %tags;

 while (<>) {
    s/^\s*($rx):\s*(\d+)/$1: $tags{$1}[$2]/;
    print;
 }
```

My thought process is that I have to first match print out the regular perl code (#!,use..etc.).Then add " my%tags=(. Then take the input file and look for the * and that's the lookup for the hash and  start parsing everything after until the next(*) or end of life. If it's another * then do it again. If it's EOF then add ");" and end. And then finish with printing the last bit of perl code. Help/ideas would be appreciated. If you're going to post *code snippets* could you go through and explain what each part is doing? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like maybe a good idea but I don't even know where I would start with this. Can you give me a recommendation on where to look for a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple script. First just parse through the input file. Lines that start with `*` will be titles, and all the following lines up until the next `*`-line will be values. We put this into a hash of arrays.

The `map` statement gives us a list of the hash key (the title), and it's values joined together with space. We put this in an array for printing. The printing itself is done with `printf`, which can be a bit difficult to use, since meta characters will mess us up. Any `%` that are to be literal must be written as `%%`. I also changed single quotes from the original to double quotes. I use single quotes on the printf pattern to avoid accidental interpolation of variables.

An alternative - possibly better one - is to not just printf at all, and simply concatenate the string in a normal fashion.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($title, %hash);
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^\*(.+)$/) {
        $title = $1;
    } else {
        push @{$hash{$title}}, $_;
    }
}

my @args = ( map { $_, join(' ', @{$hash{$_}}) } keys %hash );
printf '#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %%tags = (
        "%s" => [ qw ( %s ) ],
        "%s" => [ qw ( %s ) ]);

my $rx = join "|", keys %%tags;

while (<>) {
    s/^\s*($rx):\s*(\d+)/$1: $tags{$1}[$2]/;
    print;
}', @args;

__DATA__
*firsttitle
nameA
nameB
nameC
*secondtitle
xnameA
xnameB
xnameC
```

**Update:**

This will use a different method of printing, which will be more stable.

```
my @args = ( map { "    '$_' => [ qw ( @{$hash{$_}} ) ],\n" } keys %hash );
print '#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %tags = (
', @args, '
);

my $rx = join "|", keys %tags;

while (<>) {
    s/^\s*($rx):\s*(\d+)/$1: $tags{$1}[$2]/;
    print;
}';
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: Invalid conversion in printf: "%t" at ./script2.pl line 17, <> line 90. When I give it a large input file. Note that I changed (<DATA>) to (<>). Note that line 90 is the last line in my input file. The program outputs the first two "titles" but nothing more.

Comment: Oh, that's from `%tags`.. should be `%%tags`. Weird, it worked when I tested it.

Comment: Updated answer with a way to print that does not use `printf`

Comment: @the Yes, the `printf` version was hard coded to accept two arguments, as per your request. The updated version will print all arguments.

Comment: Awesome that seems to work fine. You're a Wizard! ALso what did you mean that your second method was more "stable" what's the difference?

Comment: `printf` can cause unwanted behaviour, because of additional meta characters. Also, that version only printed 2 arguments.